# jq find the max in quoted values

Tags: json, versioning, jq, maxby

Here is my JSON `test.json`file :

```
[
  {
    "name": "nodejs",
    "version": "0.1.21",
    "apiVersion": "v1"
  },
  {
    "name": "nodejs",
    "version": "0.1.20",
    "apiVersion": "v1"
  },
  {
    "name": "nodejs",
    "version": "0.1.11",
    "apiVersion": "v1"
  },
  {
    "name": "nodejs",
    "version": "0.1.9",
    "apiVersion": "v1"
  },
  {
    "name": "nodejs",
    "version": "0.1.8",
    "apiVersion": "v1"
  }
]
```

When I use `max_by`, `jq` return `0.1.9` instead of `0.1.21` probably due to the quoted value :

```
cat test.json | jq 'max_by(.version)'
{
  "name": "nodejs",
  "version": "0.1.9",
  "apiVersion": "v1"
}
```

How can I get the element with version=0.1.21 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Semantic version](https://semver.org/) compare is not supported out of the box in `jq`. You need to play around with the fields split by `.`

```
jq 'sort_by(.version | split(".") | map(tonumber))[-1]'
```

The `split(".")` takes the string from `.version` and creates an array of fields i.e. `0.1.21` becomes an array of `[ "0", "1", "21"]` and `map(tonumber)` takes an input array and transforms the string elements to an array of digits.

The `sort_by()` function does a index wise comparison for each of the elements in the array generated from last step and sorts in the ascending order with the object containing the version `0.1.21` at the last. The notation `[-1]` is to get the last object from this sorted array.

Comment: nice one line answer. I tested with other value like `0.2.1` or `11.7` and it works in all cases. Thx

Comment: One could simply use `max_by`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an adaptation of the more general answer using jq at
[How to sort Artifactory package search result by version number with JFrog CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56024932/how-to-sort-artifactory-package-search-result-by-version-number-with-jfrog-cli)

```
def parse:
 [splits("[-.]")]
 | map(tonumber? // .) ;

max_by(.version|parse)
```

As a less robust one-liner:

```
max_by(.version | [splits("[.]")] | map(tonumber))
```

Comment: this is also useful for sorting ipv4 addresses.  i am kind of stuck trying to sort an ipv6 address, there is no 'tobase16'

Comment: @Greg - See https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Non-decimal_radices/Convert#jq

Comment: nice!  thanks.  btw, to make that one-liner work I had to add: max_by(.version|[splits("[.]")] | map(tonumber))

Comment: @greg: Fixed. Thank you.